# LyX not showing Multiplication symbol

Tags: lyx

I was writing something on LyX, and when I tried to cite the value of \hbar (planck's constant), but every time I try to preview the document in pdf, the multiplication symbol doesn't appear (see pictures) even though it appears in the document view, do you have a solution to this?

[image: document view, the multiplication sign is there]

[image: PDF view]

Note: all the other signs appear but the cross multiplication sign doesn't

---

From the comments:

as I'm using LyX, I don't think there's a code, but that's the formula it's showing in LyX code \begin_inset Formula

`$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1.054573\times10^{-34}J\,s$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show the LaTeX code that gives rise to the screenshot(s) you posted.

Comment: as I'm using LyX, I don't think there's a code, but that's the formula it's showing in LyX code \begin_inset Formula $\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1.054573\times10^{-34}J\,s$

Comment: Actually, that *is* the LaTeX code for the formula. Depending on your stylistic preferences, just change `J\,s` to either `J\times s` or `J\cdot s`.

Comment: No, the Problem is with the order of magnitude part, not the unit

Comment: Welcome. // I suspect you missed a space: `\times 10` ...

Comment: I tried to add the space by opening the lyx file in notepad, but it's still happening

Comment: Kindly see my answer. Unless some Lyx-user can replicate it, it may be hard to analyse. // Sometimes artifacts depend on the rest of the code. I suggest trying a blank Lyx-document which only holds your formula.

Comment: @MohammedAlsawafi Hi and welcome! For LyX questions in the future, it's very important to include a minimal example. You can open a .lyx file in notepad, and copy everything, and paste into here. Please read the following: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that you (a) employ whatever lyx code is needed to load the `siunitx` package and (b) replace

```
$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1.054573\times10^{-34}J\,s$
```

with

```
$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=\qty{1.054573e-34}{\joule\second}$
```

As an additional benefit, the letter symbols "J" and "s" will be rendered in upright letters, which is the SI-based standard/norm for displaying scientific units.

I'm afraid I don't use lyx, so I can't give you more advice. The LaTeX code and output come to this:

[image]

If you don't want the visual grouping in the number part, change `\qty{...}{...}` to `\qty[group-digits=false]{...}{...}`. This will inform LaTeX that visual grouping of the number part should not be performed.

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=\qty{1.054573e-34}{\joule\second}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem of rendering the output is related to the environment and/or applications you use.

The code below:

- works without and with space after `\times`
- renders correctly it `TexMakers preview (built-in viewer)`, `Acrobat reader` and `FireFox`

**TexMaker**
[image: res1]

**Acrobat**
[image: res2]

**FireFox**
[image: res3]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
As entered into Lyx: \hfill
$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1.054573\times10^{-34}J\,s$

And now with a space: \hfill
$\hbar=\frac{h}{2\pi}=1.054573\times 10^{-34}J\,s$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, I found that the problem comes from the point that I Sat up the Document in Arabic, that's why the multiplication sign doesn't want to appear. But Even after I changed the language, it doesn't work

Comment: @MohammedAlsawafi - If changing the language does not affect the formatting issue, then it's not plausible to claim that the problem is due to the document having been set up in Arabic, is it?

Comment: I wanted to change " I found " to " I thought", but it didn't allow me